# How to select MAX or COUNT in fuelPHP Orm Model

Tags: php, orm, fuelphp

I've tried these 2 way but failed...
Is select MAX or COUNT in Model Orm impossible?
(I have to use Model_Orm, not CRUD or DB)

## 1

```
Model_Foo::query()
    ->select('MAX("time") AS recent')
    ->group_by("user_id")
    ->get();
```

*result:*

```
Fuel\Core\Database_Exception [ 42000 ]:
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 
1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`) as recent` AS `t0_c0`
```

## 2

```
Model_Foo::query()
    ->select(DB::expr('MAX("time") AS recent'))
    ->group_by("user_id")
    ->get();
```

*result:*

```
Fuel\Core\PhpErrorException [ Warning ]:
Illegal offset type
```

Comment: I don't use fuelPHP but my guess is remove the quotes around MAX(time)

Comment: Thanks Daan, I have already tried no-quotes, single, double and backtick but all failed.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer here is that you don't. In an ideal world you should not be working with a subset of your model's properties or "dynamically" creating new ones as it breaks the abstraction that the ORM provides.

The easiest thing to do would be to add an extra method to your model, eg, `public static function getMaxTime()` that uses the `DB` class to construct a query to return the needed data.

To keep it in line with the ORM's table name discovery you can fetch the name of the table from the model using `Model::table()` and pass that to your `DB` query.

```
$query = DB::select(/** Enter "MAX" here */)
    ->from(static::table())
    // More stuff here
```

Comment: Thanks Uru. I see that ORM has clear purpose. Honestly it's slightly uncomfortable yet, I decided to create a new method using DB.

Comment: The current ORM is not really set up for anything like this, v2 should make it much easier to do things like this. One of the things you can do in the current ORM is to override the Model's `get()` method so you can mask the call to DB as a property, if you want that kind of abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider the ->as_object method ? 
I noticed you specified no DB::methods, but since the loop will return Orm\Model, 
I thought it might be a decent solution.

```
$dataset = Db::select(DB::expr('MAX(time) AS recent, user_id'))
->from('table')
->group_by('user_id')
->as_object('Model_Foo')
->execute();

foreach($dataset as $m) { 
    print ($m->get('recent').' '.$m->get('user_id'));
}
```

You can use the max function

```
$time_string = Model_Foo::query()->max('time');
```

It will return the value directly (not in an array or a model)

reference from fuelphp docs : 
http://fuelphp.com/docs/packages/orm/crud.html

Comment: Thanks. I know about max method, but it returns a "max" from all returned rows. I want "max" column in every grouped rows.